# How to avoid a positional option to be specified as a "regular" option in boost::program_options?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

According to the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idm45555218453872), it seems that every option has a name and can be specified as a regular option. Is it possible, to enforce an option to be only legal if specified as a positional option, and not show up in the help message as a regular option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact use-case is described later in the tutorial. You have to create two different `options_description` objects, one for the visible, an other for the hidden options, then mix them together in a third `options_description` object. When printing the help, describe only the visible one.